# What is a semibounded polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

I am stuck with the following expression, because no google search gives an answer to my problem.

Here it is: I am reading a text that states

"Let a(x) be a semibounded from below polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What does semibounded mean in this context ?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Maybe it means the polynomial function $a(x)$ is bounded *only* from below, like, say, $a(x):=|x|^2$.

Comment: thanks Pacciu, I think that's what the author intends to say ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect "semibounded" just means "bounded from one side", i.e. "bounded above or bounded below".  It would be more usual to just say "bounded below", but maybe the author is bothered by the linguistic quirk that "bounded below" does not imply "bounded".

Comment: that sounds much like what the author probably wants to say .. I think I will stick to this for now. Many thanks !